# Android touchpad

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to do touchpad in android and i have problem.
When I press mouse button i cant move my finger on screen.

Mouse listener:

```
mouse1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    client.send("B:bPressed1");
                    Log.d("Touchpad", "Mouse1 pressed");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    client.send("B:bRelease1");
                    Log.d("Touchpad", "Mouse1 released");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Override onTouchEvent to get mouse position:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int dx = (int) (x - mPreviousX);
            int dy = (int) (y - mPreviousY);
            Log.i("Touchpad", dx + "/" + dy);
            client.send("M:" + dx + "/" + dy);

        }
        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

Comment: What is a mouse button? Are you using the simulator? How do you touch the screen then?
What are you trying to achieve?
Please clarify.

Comment: I use my mobile phone. I have client and server aplication. Android is a client so i'm trying to do: press mouse1 button(left mouse button in computer) and move my finger on mobile phone screen to drag and drop something in my computer.